# trying to get an UIActivityIndicatorView added to a view, not working

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using a recipe from the iOS Recipes PragProg book, here's the original portion of code I'm using:

```
- (void)addActivityIndicatorView {

    activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;                       
    CGRect aiFrame = activityIndicatorView.frame;
    CGFloat originX = (self.view.bounds.size.width - aiFrame.size.width) / 2;
    CGFloat originY = (self.view.bounds.size.height - aiFrame.size.height) / 2;
    aiFrame.origin.x = floorl(originX);
    aiFrame.origin.y = floorl(originY);
    activityIndicatorView.frame = aiFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
}
```

I realized I wanted this activityindicator code for multiple activityIndicatorViews on my other controls that load data via the web, so this was my implementation to make reusable code and it is not showing an activityIndicator view over the control like the above code does for the one viewcontroller it's in.  Yes I do step into this code for each control that uses it, and I call [activityIndicator startAnimating]; for the activityIndicator that I pass into this function.  Guess what I'm asking is where should I look at elsewhere in the code?

```
- (void)addActivityIndicatorView:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)acitivityIndicator toView:(UIView *)view {

    acitivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    acitivityIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;                       
    CGRect aiFrame = acitivityIndicator.frame;
    CGFloat originX = (view.bounds.size.width - aiFrame.size.width) / 2;
    CGFloat originY = (view.bounds.size.height - aiFrame.size.height) / 2;
    aiFrame.origin.x = floorl(originX);
    aiFrame.origin.y = floorl(originY);
    acitivityIndicator.frame = aiFrame;
    [view addSubview:acitivityIndicator];
}
```

Comment: in main thread time is so less between start animating and stop animating that activity indicator doesnot show up u can check by detaching to new thread where u will start animating  and stop animating when u want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your method like this:

```
- (void)addActivityIndicatorView:(UIActivityIndicatorView **)activityIndicator toView:(UIView *)view {

    UIActivityIndicatorView * activeInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activeInd.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;                       
    CGRect aiFrame = activeInd.frame;
    CGFloat originX = (view.bounds.size.width - aiFrame.size.width) / 2;
    CGFloat originY = (view.bounds.size.height - aiFrame.size.height) / 2;
    aiFrame.origin.x = floorl(originX);
    aiFrame.origin.y = floorl(originY);
    activeInd.frame = aiFrame;

    *activityIndicator = activeInd;
    [view addSubview:*activityIndicator];
}
```

When you want to use the above method, pass the reference to a `UIActivityIndicatorView *` to the method for example:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIActivityIndicatorView * ai;
  [self addActivityIndicatorView: &ai toView: self.view];

  activityIndicator = ai;
}
```

Now whenever you want it to start animating:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: As you know, a method doesn't modify the actual arguments that is passed to it, instead it makes a copy of the arguments and does whatever operation inside the method on the copy. If we want to modify the actual arguments, we pass them by reference (by passing a pointer to the argument). In your case, you want to modify a pointer, that is why you should pass the reference to the pointer (pointer to pointer)

Comment: Thank's Zeus.  I knew about this in C#, in that you can't new up an object that was passed into a method, or virtually have it point to another object, only modify it's contents, call it's methods, etc., I assume this is the same in Obj-C.